# Getting "unable to attach test reporter" when trying to run tests

Tags: ios, testing, appcode

When I'm trying to run tests in appcode it looks like it's running the tests, but instead of showing me the results it says "Unable to attach test reporter to test framework or test framework quit unexpectedly".

I'm using AppCode 2.5.1.

Any ideas what causing it or how I can see the underlying issue? (logs for example)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently this is because something got corrupted on the iOS simulator.

The way to fix it is:
Go to your iOS Simulator application. Choose iOS Simulator from the top menu and choose "Reset Content and Settings..."

Thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513070/490288